# Django связывающая модель и порядковый номер

Tags: python, django

есть две модели в django

```
class Team(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=200)
   event_team = models.ManyToManyField('event', blank=True)
   ...

class Event(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=200)
   ...
```

Как мне назначить порядковый номер определенной Team, которая привязана к Event.
Создавать отдельную модель?

```
class Number_Team(models.Model):
   team = models.ManyToManyField('team', blank=True)
   event = models.ManyToManyField('event', blank=True)
   number = models.IntegerField()
```

Но как мне забивать порядковый номер именно по этому Event

Comment: А почему не использовать models.id?

Comment: Team может участвовать в нескольких Event. И каждый раз у нее будет свой порядковый номер. 
Логику вроде понимаю, а как реализовать не могу сообразить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модель промежуточной таблицы [можно задать явно](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
class Event(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=200)


class Team(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=200)
   events = models.ManyToManyField('Event', blank=True, through='Participation')
   ...


class Participation(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

А у объектов этой промежуточной модели есть своё поле `id`.

Comment: Но это свое id.А мне надо, чтобы попорядку шли номера команд в событии.
Всегда начинались с единицы. И в разных событиях может быть разное количество команд.

Нашел решение вот тут: https://djbook.ru/forum/topic/4616/
Но теперь не понимаю как заставить заполнятся эту таблицу в тот момент, когда я вношу команду в евент.

Comment: прочитал внимательнее про through. может быть вместе с моим решением и получится. Попробую

Comment: Даже если стандартное поле `id` не подойдёт, ничего не мешает в промежуточной модели завести отдельное поле, переопределить метод `save` и присваивать в нём необходимое значение этому полю.